# how to filter array of objects in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, functional-programming

I have got two arrays of objects. I want to filter data based on permissionObj.

This is coming from database. Here are arrays of sub-arrays in the permissionObj.

```
   let permissionObj = [{
            "OA deal": [{
                    label: "can view",
                    value: "can_view"
                }, {
                    label: "can create",
                    value: "can_create"
                },
                {
                    label: "can edit",
                    value: "can_edit"
                }, {
                    label: "can delete",
                    value: "can_delete"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Deposit": [{
                    label: "can view",
                    value: "can_view"
                }, {
                    label: "can create",
                    value: "can_create"
                },
                {
                    label: "can edit",
                    value: "can_edit"
                }, {
                    label: "can delete",
                    value: "can_delete"
                }
            ]
        },

        {
            "Journals": [{
                label: "can view",
                value: "can_view"
            }, {
                label: "can create",
                value: "can_create"
            }, {
                label: "can edit",
                value: "can_edit"
            }, {
                label: "can delete",
                value: "can_delete"
            }]
        },
        {
            "Deposit": [{
                label: "can view",
                value: "can_view"
            }, {
                label: "can create",
                value: "can_create"
            }, {
                label: "can edit",
                value: "can_edit"
            }, {
                label: "can delete",
                value: "can_delete"
            }]
        },


        {
            "OA deals request": []
        },
        {
            "Deposit Approval": []
        },
        {
            "Dashboard": [{
                label: "can view",
                value: "can_view"
            }, {
                label: "can create",
                value: "can_create"
            }, {
                label: "can edit",
                value: "can_edit"
            }, {
                label: "can delete",
                value: "can_delete"
            }]
        },
    ]
```

this is static data. I want to compare this data based on permission.

```
    console.log(permission)
    const PubSidebar = [{
            label: "Dashboard",
            key: "Dashboard",
            value: "can_view"
        }, {
            label: "Settings",
            key: "Settings",
            value: "can_view"
        },
        {
            label: "OA deal activities",
            key:"OA Deal" || "Deposit"|| "Corrections" ,
            content: [{
                    label: "Add oadeal",

                    key: "OA deal",
                    value: "can_create"
                },

                {
                    label: "edit oadeal ",

                    key: "OA deal",
                    value: "can_edit"
                },

                {

                    label: "view oadeal ",
                    key: "OA deal",
                    value: "can_view"

                },

                {
                    label: "Deposit for view",
                    key: "Deposit",
                    value: "can_view"
                },
                {
                    label: "Deposit for edit",
                    key: "Deposit",
                    value: "can_edit"

                },
                {
                    key: "Deposit",
                    value: "can_edit"

                },
                {
                    label: "edit Corrections",
                    key: "Corrections",
                    value: "can_edit"

                },
                {
                    label: "Add Corrections",
                    key: "Corrections",
                    value: "can_create"

                },

                {
                    label: "view Corrections",
                    key: "Corrections",
                    value: "can_view"

                }
            ]
        },
        { key:"Journals"
            label: "Journal for publishers",
            content: [{
                    label: "Add Journal",
                    key: "Journals",
                    value: "can_create"
                },
                {
                    label: "Journals List",
                    key: "Journals",
                    value: "can_view"

                },

            ]
        },
    ];
```

I am trying to filter the PubSidebar array of the object based on permissionObj array of objects. here is my trying code.

```
 let permission =
      permissionObj.filter(
        x => Object.values(x)[0].length !== 0
      );

    const result =
      PubSidebar &&
      PubSidebar.reduce((accumulator, currentvalue) => {
        let filterObj = permission && permission.find(f => f[currentvalue.key]);
        // console.log("filterObj", filterObj);
        if (filterObj) {
          if (currentvalue.value) {
            accumulator.push(currentvalue);
          }
          if (currentvalue.content) {
            console.log(currentvalue);
            currentvalue.content =
              currentvalue &&
              currentvalue.content &&
              currentvalue.content.filter(
                f =>
                  filterObj[currentvalue.key] &&
                  filterObj[currentvalue.key].some(
                    s =>
                      s.value &&
                      s.value.toLowerCase() &&
                      s.value === f.value.toLowerCase()
                  )
              );
            accumulator.push(currentvalue);
          }
        }
        return accumulator;
      }, []);
```

Here is my problem, I have been faced is that I don't want to get can_edit, can_delete  if it doesn't match with permission objects in corrections. In my permission objects, There is no Corrections.

I want to filtering pubsidebar based on key and value of permissionObj objects. It will be this format value

```
    // My Accepted Output would be :


    const output = [{
            label: "Dashboard",
            key: "Dashboard",
            value: "can_view"
        },
        {   key:"OA Deal" || "Deposit",
            label: "OA deal activities",
            content: [{
                    label: "Add oadeal",
                    key: "OA deal",
                    value: "can_create"
                },

                {
                    label: "edit oadeal ",
                    key: "OA deal",
                    value: "can_edit"
                },

                {
                    label: "view oadeal ",
                    key: "OA deal",
                    value: "can_view"

                },

                {
                    label: "Deposit for view",
                    key: "Deposit",
                    value: "can_view"
                },
                {
                    label: "Deposit for edit",
                    key: "Deposit",
                    value: "can_edit"

                },
                {
                    key: "Deposit",
                    value: "can_edit"

                },


            ]
        },
        { key:"Journals"
            label: "Journal for publishers",
            content: [{
                    label: "Add Journal",
                    key: "Journals",
                    value: "can_create"
                },
                {
                    label: "Journals List",
                    key: "Journals",
                    value: "can_view"

                },

            ]
        },
    ];
```

Comment: waiting , I am writing full question again

Comment: I edited my question . can you see

Comment: if my items are coming with sub-arrays , I want to filter with key and value , my key will be permission property name and value will be can_view, can_create and anything . I want to match and return data

Comment: Your `permissionObj` does not have `OA deal activities`. What's rule to have `OA deal activities` in result array? It would be great if you have less data in your examples. It is really hard to understand what it is going on for me. Thanks.

Comment: I just edit again ,  I added key by using OR operator  below oa deal activities  because , I want to add inside OA Deal activities based on parent key

Comment: before that you wrote a code based on  value , now , I want to filter based on key and value . if key and value is true , then show data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937465/how-to-filtering-array-of-sub-array-of-objects-and-array-of-sub-array-of-objects I think now you can understand